# SQLite3 Encoding Latin-1 data

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, encoding

I have a CSV file that contains a number of rows with data that is in Latin-1, for example

```
 Àird a' Bhàigh
```

I am trying to load this data into an SQLite using a DictReader and every option I have tried never creates the right data in the SQLite.

Option 1: Unicode

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open('data.txt', "rb"), delimiter=':')
for row in reader:
     to_db = [unicode(row[0], "utf8")]
     cur.execute("INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES (?);", to_db)
```

Option 2: Decode

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open('data.txt', "rb"), delimiter=':')
for row in reader:
     to_db = [row[0].decode('latin-1')]
     cur.execute("INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES (?);", to_db)
```

Option 3: Decode and Encode

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open('data.txt', "rb"), delimiter=':')
for row in reader:
     to_db = [row[0].decode('latin-1').encode('utf-8')]
     cur.execute("INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES (?);", to_db)
```

For each option I get a variety of errors including

```
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 4

You must not use 8-bit bytestrings
```

so I then changed the connection to:

```
connection.text_factory = str
```

Again I just get the black question marks in the data.

This is very frustrating as it is very simple to set the encoding with something like PostgreSQL

Hopefully someone can help with a solution

Thanks

Updated:

Here is some lines of the file

```
2467:NB2601:Àird a' Bhàigh:NB20:57:55.1:6:37.2:901500:126500:W:WI:N Eil:Na h-Eileanan an Iar:H:01-MAR-1993:I:14:0:0
2468:NB2034:Àird a' Chaolais:NB22:58:12.6:6:45.5:934500:120500:W:WI:N Eil:Na h-Eileanan an Iar:X:01-MAR-1993:I:8:13:0
2469:NL6197:Àird a' Chaolais:NL68:56:56.7:7:34.1:797500:61500:W:WI:N Eil:Na h-Eileanan an Iar:X:01-MAR-1993:I:31:0:0
2470:NB4232:Àird a' Chleirich:NB42:58:12.4:6:23:932500:142500:W:WI:N Eil:Na h-Eileanan an Iar:X:01-MAR-1993:I:8:0:0
2471:NM4118:Àird a' Chrainn:NM40:56:17.3:6:10.6:718500:141500:W:AR:Arg & Bt:Argyll and Bute:X:01-MAR-1993:I:48:0:0
2472:NM7331:Àird a' Chrotha:NM62:56:25.3:5:40.4:731500:173500:W:AR:Arg & Bt:Argyll and Bute:X:01-JUL-1996:U:49:0:0
2473:NB2045:Àird a' Ghobhann:NB24:58:18.5:6:46.3:945500:120500:W:WI:N Eil:Na h-Eileanan anIar:X:01-JAN-1995:U:8:0:0
2474:NF7445:Àird a' Mhachair:NF64:57:23:7:25.1:845500:74500:W:WI:N Eil:Na h-Eileanan an Iar:O:05-JAN-2012:U:22:0:0
2475:NF8379:Àird a' Mhòrain:NF86:57:41.6:7:18.8:879500:83500:W:WI:N Eil:Na h-Eileanan an Iar:H:01-MAR-1993:I:18:0:0
2476:NB1810:Àird a' Mhulaidh:NB00:57:59.7:6:45.9:910500:118500:W:WI:N Eil:Na h-Eileanan an Iar:O:01-MAY-1997:U:13:14:0
2477:NF7974:Àird a' Phuind:NF66:57:38.8:7:22.4:874500:79500:W:WI:N Eil:Na h-Eileanan an Iar:X:01-MAR-1993:I:18:0:0
```

You can see it is the third column that I am struggling with.

This is what it looks like in the SQLite using the browser via Firefox

[image]

UPDATE 2: When i do print repr(row[0]) i get the following

```
"\xc0ird a' Bh\xe0igh"
"\xc0ird a' Chaolais"
"\xc0ird a' Chaolais"
"\xc0ird a' Chleirich"
"\xc0ird a' Chrainn"
"\xc0ird a' Chrotha"
"\xc0ird a' Ghobhann"
"\xc0ird a' Mhachair"
"\xc0ird a' Mh\xf2rain"
"\xc0ird a' Mhulaidh"
"\xc0ird a' Phuind"
```

How can I make sure it is Latin1, that is what charset I believe those characters to be part of

Comment: I have to check: you are 100% certain the data in the file is Latin-1 encoded?

Comment: The text factory is only used when *retrieving* data from the database, not when inserting.

Comment: The `sqlite3` adapter otherwise deals entirely in UTF-8. How are you verifying that you are getting the right data in the database?

Comment: In other words, if `latin-1` is the correct codec, then `to_db = [row[0].decode('latin-')]` is the correct method and everything works correctly from there. If it doesn't for you, then either you are using the wrong tool (or a misconfigured tool) to verify the data *or* the CSV is not encoded with Latin-1.

Comment: What does `print repr(row[0])` look like? Can you give us some sample data?

Comment: You do indeed have what looks like Latin 1 input. Decoding that with `row[0].decode('latin-1')` is the correct way to turn that into a Unicode object and insertion works correct from there. What goes wrong is how you are displaying it. What program are you using to read the SQLite database; it is **that** program that is reading the data wrong.